# Feb 29th error on formula for datetime field

Tags: formula, error-messages

I have a formula that is throwing up the 29th feb leap year error etc but for the life I cant see why?

The error message is

"Computed an invalid date, such as February 29th on a non-leap year. Please contact your administrator; formula fields can cause such errors."

Anyone help at all?

```
IF(
    MONTH(
        DATEVALUE(
            DATETIMEVALUE(
                TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) 
                + "-" 
                + TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()))
                + "-" 
                + TEXT(DAY(TODAY()))
                + " "
                + TEXT(HOUR(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
                + TEXT(MINUTE(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
                + ":00"
            )
        ) 
    ) = 2 
    &&
    DAY(
        DATEVALUE(
            DATETIMEVALUE(
                TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) 
                + "-" 
                + TEXT(MONTH(TODAY())) 
                + "-" 
                + TEXT(DAY(TODAY()))
                + " " 
                + TEXT(HOUR(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
                + TEXT(MINUTE(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
                + ":00"
            )
        ) 

    ) = 29 
    && 
    YEAR(
        DATEVALUE(
            DATETIMEVALUE(
                TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) 
                + "-" 
                + TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()))
                + "-" 
                + TEXT(DAY(TODAY()))
                + " "
                + TEXT(HOUR(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
                + TEXT(MINUTE(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
                + ":00"
            )
        ) 
    ) / 4 == 0, 
        DATETIMEVALUE(
            TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) 
            + "-" 
            + TEXT(03)
            + "-" 
            + TEXT(01)
            + " "
            + TEXT(HOUR(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
            + TEXT(MINUTE(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
            + ":00"
        ),
        DATETIMEVALUE(
            TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) 
            + "-" 
            + TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()))
            + "-" 
            + TEXT(DAY(TODAY())
            + Campaign__r.Days_Till_1__c
        )
        + " "
        + TEXT(HOUR(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
        + TEXT(MINUTE(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
        + ":00"
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Big blocks of code are hard to interpret, so I've made an effort to break it up into more manageable pieces. It'll also help if you [edit] your question to be _very specific_ about the issues that you're facing. What is the "Feb 29th leap year error"? and what are the errors you group under "etc"? Providing specific examples will help here.

Comment: About the only things I can say right now are that dividing the year by 4 is not sufficient, and that this would likely be a lot easier in Apex. The general formula for "is it a leap year" is: - every 4 years - except for every hundred years - unless the year is also divisible by 400

Comment: Thanks Derek.. I couldnt find where to edit but have done so now. The error message was "Computed an invalid date, such as February 29th on a non-leap year. Please contact your administrator; formula fields can cause such errors."

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to calculate the remainder of the leap year, but you just divided it by 4 instead. This might fix it assuming you don't care about the 100 year rule and the 400 year rule that @Derek F mentioned in his excellent comment.

```
IF(
    MONTH(
        DATEVALUE(
            DATETIMEVALUE(
                TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) 
                + "-" 
                + TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()))
                + "-" 
                + TEXT(DAY(TODAY()))
                + " "
                + TEXT(HOUR(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
                + TEXT(MINUTE(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
                + ":00"
            )
        ) 
    ) = 2 
    &&
    DAY(
        DATEVALUE(
            DATETIMEVALUE(
                TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) 
                + "-" 
                + TEXT(MONTH(TODAY())) 
                + "-" 
                + TEXT(DAY(TODAY()))
                + " " 
                + TEXT(HOUR(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
                + TEXT(MINUTE(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
                + ":00"
            )
        ) 

    ) = 29 
    && 
    MOD(
        YEAR(
            DATEVALUE(
                DATETIMEVALUE(
                    TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) 
                    + "-" 
                    + TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()))
                    + "-" 
                    + TEXT(DAY(TODAY()))
                    + " "
                    + TEXT(HOUR(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
                    + TEXT(MINUTE(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
                    + ":00"
                )
            ) 
        )
     , 4) = 0, 

        DATETIMEVALUE(
            TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())) 
            + "-" 
            + TEXT(03)
            + "-" 
            + TEXT(01)
            + " "
            + TEXT(HOUR(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
            + TEXT(MINUTE(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
            + ":00"
        ),
        DATETIMEVALUE(
            TEXT(YEAR(TODAY() + Campaign__r.Days_Till_1__c)) 
            + "-" 
            + TEXT(MONTH(TODAY() + Campaign__r.Days_Till_1__c))
            + "-" 
            + TEXT(DAY(TODAY() + Campaign__r.Days_Till_1__c)

        )
        + " "
        + TEXT(HOUR(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
        + TEXT(MINUTE(Campaign__r.Step_1_Send_Time__c ))
        + ":00"
    ) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks Kasper.. I did try your fix but still receiving the error "Computed an invalid date, such as February 29th on a non-leap year. Please contact your administrator; formula fields can cause such errors."

Comment: Hi @DavidForder. I think the problem was in your last datetime calculation. I think you tried to add some days to the day part of the date. That means that if the date is 30 th, and you add 10 days it will try to parse a date with day is 40 into a datetime stamp. That of course fails. I tried to fix it. If you are intend on calculation the datetime for the first of the next month (that's a guess) then there is an easier way by using addmonths.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with the leap year.
You can refer a simple formula below:

If mon = 2 & day = 29, I used DATE(year, 2, 28) + 1, system will auto calculate to 29-Feb or 1-Mar

```
IF(
AND(
  MONTH(S_date__c)=2,
  DAY(S_date__c)=29
),
DATE(YEAR(S_date__c)+10,2,28) + 1,
DATE(YEAR(S_date__c)+10,MONTH(S_date__c),DAY(S_date__c)))
```